# Database Design for file uploading on posts, comments and profile pages

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am new to web development and am trying to implement a website where users can upload photos and other files (i.e. .doc, .xls, .ppt, .txt, .pdf,etc...) on profile pages, posts and comments. I am using an s3 bucket for the file storage and will use a mysql database to store the file urls and other associative data. What I am confused about is the following:

Which of these is the best idea?

a) create a files tables for each of the following: profiles,posts,comments and then get all the files associated with the id(A FK) of the specified object(the post, the comment, or the profile).

b) create one files table that has a field named "type" which can be either "profile","post","comment"
and a field named "id" which is a FK of the the id of the table specified in the "type" field.

c) use a completely different schema that anyone finds more advantageous

EDIT: I want each file to be associated to the uploader(user_id) but also attached to the entity it was uploaded on(i.e. profile,post,comment)

Comment: This is not a fleshed out enough question. For different reasons these different approaches might work. You need to assert more invariants and perhaps some reasons why one or another might be uncomfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create one table `Files` like

```
Files
|id|file_path|...(other information about the file)
```

If a `Post`, `Comment` and `Profile` can contain only one file you can add the `file_id` directly in the tables like

```
Posts
|id|data|...|file_id|
```

If they can have more then one file you'll need a mapping table like:

```
Posts
|id|data|...

Posts_Files_Mapping
|post_id|file_id|
```

Comment: I guess I would need some mapping tables because for all of the cases (posts,comments,profiles) you can upload more than one file

Comment: Then you need a mapping table for each, this should be the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

Do files always belong to the same "thing", in your case probably a User, or a UserProfile or a Person?

In that case, I would define a set of generic fields that apply to all types of files and include a 'type' field to distinguish between file types.

Something like this could work

```
- User/Person/UserProfile/Account
userId (PK)
firstname
lastname

- File
fileId (PK)
title
description
fileType
userId (FK)
size
```

Now, this is a model for if you want your files linked to a User directly, but you might want to have them linked to the Posts they were placed, like in Facebook. In that case I would embed a link to the file as part of the post's contents and link the post to the user.

It depends on what your needs are.

Comment: yes, a file is owned by the uploader(user) and is associated to the type of content it was uploaded on(post,comment,profile page)

Comment: It is hard to come up with a proper database model based on so little info, really. You are thinking from a display perspective. The main question in you are asking yourself is 'I need files displayed in location X, Y and Z'. How do I represent that in a database. I think you should read up on some database design tutorials and after that ask yourself the question, 'how do the entities in my system really fit together'. Or you should give more context about what your exact intentions are. How 'files' are to be displayed, where, how they are entered, etc.

Comment: This tutorial may be helpful http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/intro.html It is aimed at beginners in database design

Comment: Thanks. I'll read through that asap. I have read up on some other tutorials and database normalization and understand some of the basic concepts but i could definitely use a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are new to web development.

Pehaps you should consider skipping relational type database like mysql and use a "NOSQL" database like [mongodb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB).

There many benefits to [mongodb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) but one of the major one is the concept of "scheme-less" database which allows you to store different types of data within the same collection/table.

But don't think this is a easy way out, you still have to have a good understanding of the best way to model your data.

Comment: In the future I might move over to a NOSQL solution even though I've heard mongodb has a relatively low learning curve. For now though, I thought it would be more intelligent to use technology I am more familiar with(mysql). But I am curious, how would NOSQL make the problem I posed above more simple?

Comment: It wouldn't. Both traditional, relational databases and flat nosql databases have a learning curve and require you to think about how you should structure your data. If you have to learn anyway, you are probably better of digging into relational databases, because they are used much more often and if you know one, you have the basic knowledge to work with any relational db.

Comment: When you said you are new to development I assumed that also applied  to mysql. But if you familar with mysql, then you should stick to it. With mongodb you could store each "row of data" as a document. But unlike rows in a relational database the fields with a document are not fixed. Therefore each document can have different data depending on what information you had for user/profile etc.